# How to disable fixed header on Mobile with CSS

Tags: php, css

Here is my code for a fixed header.

```
<?php } ?>
<header id="header" class="<?php if ( theme_option( THEME_OPTIONS, 'enable_header_fixed' ) == 'true' ) : ?> fixed_header <?php else : ?> relative_header <?php endif; ?>">
```

I would like to incorporate CSS to disable fixed on mobile. My website is 780webdesign.com if you need to view source. Thanks much.

EDIT: Still not resolved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make the header "no longer fixed" but still visible, you can put it back to the default value, which is `static`.

```
/* To revert a fixed element to the default position */
.fixed-header {
    position: static;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Currently you're telling it to not display at all. You'd want to adjust the position of the element. So you would do something like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .fixed-header {
        position: relative;
}
```

You may have to add some additional properties to fix positioning but that would be a good start.

EDIT:

After getting linked to the site, and taking a look this is what you would want to use.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
    .fixed-header{
       position: relative;
       margin-bottom: -270px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. Is there a way I could incorporate it into the PHP code directly instead of using CSS?

Comment: @MatthewGalpin you could switch to a different header all together - but that would be way more work. CSS would be the easiest and most efficient way to make that happen.  Can you post a link to the site so we can see it "in the wild"?

Comment: @MatthewGalpin I updated my answer to reflect the correct CSS to get the effect you're looking for.

Comment: No cigar. Thanks for your efforts. I'll keep searching

Comment: @MatthewGalpin I would assume that your JS is probably overwriting the CSS. You could also try adding !important tags and see if that helps. It was working fine for me when using dev tools, but that doesnt account for on page load.

Answer (score 1):

You have inline styles which are going to cause issues with your classes, so you need `!important` on anyhting you use to overwrite them. The following will resolve you issue from what I see:

```
#header.fixed_header {position: relative !important;}
#page {margin-top: 0px !important;}
```

This code just needs wrapping in a css media query to set it to happen at what your preferred widths are.

Comment: Dude, it worked! You're my hero.
If anyone is interested, this is the full code:

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
#header.fixed_header {position: relative !important;}
#page {margin-top: 0px !important;}
}